# Web scraping with python's request module requires submit button

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to web scrape my grades off of [this website](https://parent-portland.cascadetech.org/portland/Login_Parent_PXP.aspx?regenerateSessionId=True).

I have this which enters the login info (I think):

```
import requests
def main():
    login = {'username':'USERNAME', 'password':'PASSWORD'}
    url = 'https://parent-portland.cascadetech.org/portland/Login_Parent_PXP.aspx?regenerateSessionId=True'
    r = requests.post(url, login)
    r.submit()
    print(r.text)
main()
```

It looks like you  have to press a button.

```
<input name="Submit1" id="Submit1" value="Login" cssclass="btn" text="Login" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();" type="submit">
```

However, I just learned this today and I have no idea how to do this with the requests module.

Comment: You need to find the form, and see what URL it submits to as its `action`, then send your request to that URL.

Comment: how about putting some headers, also could you let us know what's the error you are getting, or are you landing on the login page again.

Comment: I don't know if it's actually necessary to click the button (there might be some other way), but if it is you should check out selenium. This script should be fairly straightforward to achieve with selenium. The downside is that it actually opens up a browser to do the scrape.

Comment: @Barmar I found the url but I think it's the url I was posting to anyway
action="./Login_Parent_PXP.aspx?regenerateSessionId=True"

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything special. Pressing the button submits the form, and that's what you're doing by sending a request to the URL.

Comment: The `onclick` attribute in the submit button is just to disable the button, to prevent the user from accidentally clicking it twice.

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't seem to load the page's HTML it should go to after submitting the form.

Comment: @GaurangShah I'm landing on the login page again.

Comment: You have to submit the hidden fields too. The problem is that they are dynamic, so you'll have to scrape them.